# 2016 Audi — Audit trail for Central Locking?

Tags: audi, central-locking

A hopefully straightforward question: does anyone know if a central-locking audit trail is kept by the car for any period of time? Such a thing would contain record of locks/unlocks, door opens, etc.

Looks like someone had their dinner in my car and helped themselves to a couple of bits along the way — I would love to confirm that I failed to lock it (of course I'm sure I did lock it ...) and see when it happened.

Comment: Not usually. At most I've seen a list of alarm inducing events and even then there was not time stamp just newest to oldest. The assumption is that when something happens you are most likely in the car.